# floated items are outside parent div

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with floated UL's. I have floated several UL's to the left and after I do that they end up outside the parent div. I have added `overflow: hidden` to parent div with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.competitive_analysis {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.clean_sense {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}

.jan_pro {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}

.maids {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.molly_maids {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="competetive_analysis">
  <h2> Competetive Analysis</h2>
  <h3> Website Keywords</h3>
  <p> Tampa, Florida, Apartment Cleaning, Ozone, Apartments, Residents, Clean Sense, Grout Cleaning, Pasco County, Hillsborough County, Pinellas County, Sarasota County</p>

  <div class="clean_sense">
    <ul>
      <li> <strong>Clean Sense</strong></li>
      <li>Global Rank: N/A</li>
      <li>Bounce Rate: N/A</li>
      <li>Daily Time On-Site: N/A</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="jan_pro">
    <ul>
      <li> <em>Jan-Pro</em></li>
      <li>Global Rank: 574,373</li>
      <li>Bounce Rate: %57.10</li>
      <li>Daily Time On-Site: 2:54</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="maids">
    <ul>
      <li> <em>Maids</em></li>
      <li>Global Rank: 205,032</li>
      <li>Bounce Rate: %56.60</li>
      <li>Daily Time On-Site: 1:60</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="molly_maids">
    <ul>
      <li> <em>Molly Maids</em></li>
      <li>Global Rank: 124,641</li>
      <li>Bounce Rate: %41.50</li>
      <li>Daily Time On-Site: 5:44</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float` removes the element from the document flow, but I don't see what is wrong with what you have here, assuming you just want those `div`'s horizontal.  Also, you're not floating the `ul`'s, you're floating the parent element.

Comment: I would use display: inline-table; instead of float: left;

Answer (score 0):

there is spelling mistake (mismatch rather) in class name in html "competetive_analysis" vs that in css "competitive_analysis"